# protractor - how to get the result of an array of promises into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, protractor

I got an array of promises from this code: `element.all(by.repeater('unit in units'))`, and I am finding it really difficult to get the data into another array:

```
element.all(by.repeater('unit in units')).then(function (arr) {
    var items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].getText().then(function(text) {
        items.push(text);
      });
    }

   //PROBLEM ITEMS is Empty
   console.log(items);
});
```

Answer (score 33):

Managed to get the same result on a simpler way avoiding using Q and the repeater. Using the inbuilt map does the trick.

```
var tabs = element.all(by.css('.unitTabs li a')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});

tabs.then(function (result) {
    var sorted = _.sortBy(result, function (name) { return name; });
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        expect(result[i]).toBe(sorted[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm glad that someone is using my map implementation!

Comment: Thanks Andres, quite handy util, do you have any kind of blog/wiki were we can see some more detail about that pleas? the  reason I asked if because I found it hanging in and test somewhere on the web rather than a proper documentation

Comment: You could also use ```protractor.promise.all```, see http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/

Comment: What one should expect in `tabs` map, what is the key what is the value? Could you please add it to answer?

Answer (score 8):

Fixed using Q

```
var Q = require('q');

element.all(by.repeater('unit in units')).then(function (arr) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        promises.push(arr[i].getText());
    }

    Q.all(promises).done(function (result) {
        // print the results when the lookups and processing are done                
        console.log(result.length);
        console.log(result);                
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer but... what is Q please? :)

Comment: A tool for making and composing asynchronous promises in JavaScript 
http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/

Comment: You need to install q with "npm install q --save-dev" in your application repository

Comment: Don't use Q if you can avoid it, it is very slow and consumes a lot of memory. Consider using bluebird instead.

Answer (score 2):

npm Q is the first thing to do then use requirejs on top of your script like that

```
      var Q = require('q');

      element.all(by.repeater('object in objects')).then(function (arr) {
          var promises = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              promises.push(arr[i].getText());
          }

          Q.all(promises).done(function (result) {
              // print the results when the lookups and processing are done
              console.log(result.length);
              console.log(result);
          });
      });
```

BTW I think my second option it is cleaner.