# protractor return array of values from repeater

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am looking for an easy way to return an array of values from protractor's `all.(by.repeater)`

Basically, I just want an easy way to make an array of `usernames` given a repeater like `user in users`.

Right now I'm building it like this:

```
allUsers = element.all(by.repeater('user in users').column('user.username')).then(function(array){
  var results = []
  var elemLength = array.length
  for(var n = 0; n < elemLength; n++){
    array[n].getText().then(function(username){
      results.push(username)
    })
  }
  return results
});
expect(allUsers).toContain(newUser)
```

Is there a more concise, reusable way to do this built into protractor/jasmine that I just can't find?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AS alecxe said, use map to do this.  This will return a deferred that will resolve with the values in an array, so if you have this:

```
var mappedVals = element.all(by.repeater('user in users').column('user.username')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});
```

It will resolve like this:

```
mappedVals.then(function (textArr) {
    // textArr will be an actual JS array of the text from each node in your repeater
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've successfully used `map()` for this before:

```
element.all(by.repeater('user in users').column('user.username')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});
```

When I researched the topic I took the solution from:

- [protractor - how to get the result of an array of promises into another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736191/protractor-how-to-get-the-result-of-an-array-of-promises-into-another-array)